# Workaround overwriting local variable in for loop?

Tags: python

I have code something like this:

```
funcs = []

class NumberContainer():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.number = num

items = []
for i in range(5):
    items.append(NumberContainer(i+1))

for item in items:
    number = item.number
    n = number
    def my_func(x):
        res = x < n
        print("is {} less than {}? {}".format(x, number, res))
        return res
    funcs.append(my_func)

for f in funcs:
    f(3)
```

this outputs:

```
is 3 less than 5? True
is 3 less than 5? True
is 3 less than 5? True
is 3 less than 5? True
is 3 less than 5? True
```

but obviously what I really want is for it to check the range of numbers.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `def my_func(x, number=number, n=n):`

Comment: But you call with 3 hardcoded every time -> `f(3)`

Comment: @wim His issue is with the `n` variable, which he expects to be different in each closure.

Comment: @wim I think OP hoped `number` wouldn't always be `5`.

Comment: Python variable scope is by function -- each iteration of the `for` loop doesn't create a new variable `n`.

Comment: Why are you comparing with `n`, but printing `number`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution (as is often the case) is to not use globals (or non-locals). Your function's input should come from parameters and output should be the return value. As for constructing functions I would use some kind of factory..

In this case I would write:

```
def comparison_factory(compare_to):
   def compare_func(x):
      res = x < compare_to
      print("is {} less than {}? {}".format(x, compare_to, res))
      return res
   return compare_func

funcs = [ comparison_factory(n) for n in range(1,5) ]

for f in funcs:
   f(3)
```